# Fatal Error class not found

Tags: php, class, require

Good night.

Please excuse me for my english, I'm from Costa Rica...

I am working with PHP POO and I have a problem.

The error is the next:

> Fatal error: Class 'mysql' not found in /home/casa/public_html/guaria/clases/verificaSesion.php on line 15

All my .php files are in the "clases" folder.

conexion.php

```
<?php
/**
* Clase de MySQL
*/
class mysql
{
    private $con;
    private $res;
    private $reg;
    public function conecta()
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","casa","trabajo1");
        if (!$con) {
            echo "Error al conectar a base de datos".mysqli_error();
        }
        mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES'utf8'");
        $this->con = $con;
    }
    public function consulta($sql)
    {
        $res = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
        $this->res = $res;
        return;
    }
    public function devuelve()
    {
        $reg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->res);
        return $reg;
    }
    public function desconecta()
    {
        mysqli_close();
    }
}
require_once 'acciones.php';
?>
```

And this is my verificaSesion.php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';

/**
* Clase de Verificación de Sesión
*/
class verificaSesion
{
    public $mysql;
    public $usuario;
    public $password;
    public $direccion;
    function __construct($direccion)
    {
        $this->mysql = new mysql();
        $this->mysql->conecta();
        $this->usuario = $_COOKIE["usuario"];
        $this->password = $_COOKIE["password"];
        $this->direccion = $direccion;
    }
    public function verifica()
    {
        $res = $this->mysql->consulta("select count(*) as total from usuarios where usuario='".$this->usuario."' and password='".$this->password."'");
        $reg = $this->mysql->devuelve();
        $tot = $reg["total"];
        if ($tot == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    public function obtiene()
    {
        $res = $this->mysql->consulta("select * from usuarios where usuario='".$this->usuario."'");
        $reg = $this->mysql->devuelve();
        return $reg;
    }
    public function redirecciona()
    {
        header("Location: ".$this->direccion);
    }
    public function ejecuta()
    {
        if ($this->verifica() == 1) {
            return $this->obtiene();
        } else {
            $this->redirecciona();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Both files are in the same folder so I dont understand the problem...

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using mysql and mysqli?

Comment: @EternalHour Look over the OP's code again, *very carefully* ;)

Comment: @EternalHour because I cant make a class called mysqli...

Comment: As Fred helped me realize, you can't create a class called mysql either :)

Comment: *Ah,* two very good points. ;)

Comment: Of course I can make a class called mysql because mysql dont work with OPP... When I cant make a class because of the name it shows an error:Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class mysqli in.. So, I can make a class called mysql because it dont shows any error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally make my code Work. By the way I can create a class called mysql because mysql function is not a class like mysqli.
if it could not create a class called mysql it would show an error like:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class mysql

But it doesn't..

The solution was to change the require_once in verificaSesion.php to:

```
require_once 'clases/conexion.php';
```

I dont really understand why, because both files verificaSesion and conexion are in the same folder but it works...
Anyway, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because mysql is a reserved keyword for the mysql connection library.

How to Fix It:

Just use a different name